# Why does the return-statement not quit the method?

Tags: java, return

I'm working in Junit/Java for an assignment. This method should go to the correct if-statement, advance the day in a way the common calendar does and then exit the whole method.

I've googled this problem extensively. The only pages I've found, point me to the exact thing i'm trying to do. It is likely that i'm missing something, I just don't know what. When I run the tests through the debugger, I see that Java does go to the correct statement, it just "ignores" the return.

```
protected final void advanceDay() {
    int[] highMonth = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12};
    boolean isMonth31 = false;

    for (int x : highMonth) {
        if (this.monthFirstDay == x) {
            isMonth31 = true;
        }
    }
    //checks if month has 31 days

    if (this.dayFristDay >= 30) {
        if (this.dayFristDay == 31) {
            this.dayFristDay = 1;
            this.monthFirstDay++;
            return;
        }
        //if it's the 31st, then proceed to the next month, the day is set to one.

        if (this.dayFristDay == 31 && this.monthFirstDay == 12) {
            this.dayFristDay = 1;
            this.monthFirstDay = 1;
            return;
        }
        //if it's december the 31st, set the date to january 1st

        if (isMonth31 && this.dayFristDay == 30) {
            this.dayFristDay++;
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        } 
        //if the month has 31 days, but it is the 30st, just advance the day.

        if (!isMonth31 && this.dayFristDay == 30) {
            this.monthFirstDay++;
            this.dayFristDay = 1;
            System.out.println("");
            return;
            //if the month has 30 days and it is the 30st, advance the month and set the day to one. 
        }

    }

    if (this.dayFristDay == 28 && this.monthFirstDay == 2) {
        this.monthFirstDay++;
        this.dayFristDay = 1;
        System.out.println("");
        return;
    }
    //if it's the 28st of february, advance to march the first.
    System.out.println("");
    this.dayFristDay++;
}
```

The prints are meant as breakpoints for the debugger. If any of the the if-statements is true, I should never get to the last print. But I keep getting to the last print, while it's not supposed to.

EDIT: to reproduce the error:
     // to use in different class in the same package
     Cockpit testCP = new Cockpit(28, 2);
     testCP.advanceDay();

```
public class Cockpit {

private int dayFristDay;
private int monthFirstDay;

public Cockpit(int dayFristDay, int monthFirstDay) {
    this.dayFristDay = dayFristDay;
    this.monthFirstDay = monthFirstDay;
}

//advanceDay method as a above

     protected String getCurrentDay() {
         return this.dayFristDay + "-" + this.monthFirstDay;
     }
}
```

Comment: The `return` will end the method. You are having wrong assumptions. If the method does not end, you are not hitting the statements. Place some prints to confirm if you enter or not, or use your debugger.

Comment: Are you reaching `if` statements or their bodies?

Comment: @Zabuza Both the print and the debugger confirm that it goes into the februay-28-if and to the last one as if the return does not exist.

Comment: @Andronicus I do not see the difference. I'm testing (and reaching) the print-line i've put in the if's to test.

Comment: @JayAberlour post a complete minimal example that we can copy, paste and run by ourselves to reproduce the problem. But I doubt you'll be able to do that, because if `return` didn't work, I think someone would have noticed by now.

Comment: This is a really complicated approach to the problem: just define an array containing the month lengths, and then check if (day+1) exceeds the current month's length.

Comment: @AndyTurner Perhaps. But that does not explain my issue.

Comment: I replaced the very last println in your method by `System.out.println("GOODBYE");`, then ran your code, and GOODBYE was never printed. So `return` works as expected.

Comment: Seems like the code in question wasn't properly recompiled. Works for me too.

Answer (score 4):

```
Cockpit testCP = new Cockpit(28, 2);    
this.testCP.advanceDay();
```

Line 2 isn't invoking `advanceDay` on the instance you created on line 1. You're invoking it on the instance referred to by some member variable.

Remove the `this`.

[Ideone demo, showing that return works](https://ideone.com/AxDU7a)

Comment: True, but irrelevant to my issue. Bug also happens without this.

Comment: @JayAberlour then you're going to have to provide a better example to reproduce the issue, because I copied and pasted your code, and return worked (link in answer).